# JSON to java conversion

Tags: java, json

I want to convert following JSON into java Object . Please sugest  simplest way . I don't wan to use escape character while converting the JSON String.

```
{
  "sid": "S-121",
  "name": "Sumit",
  "address": {
    "pin": "560068",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "street": {
      "stid": "1111",
      "landMark": "DX Apartment",
      "postOffice": "Bomanhalli"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use escape character while conversion   { \"sid\": \"S-121\", \"name\": "\Sumit\", "\address\": { "\pin\": "\560068\", "\state\": "\Karnataka\", "\street\": { \"stid\": \"1111\", \"landMark\": \"DX Apartment\", \"postOffice\": \"Bomanhalli\" } } }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
     Street strt= new Street("1111", "DX Apartment", "Bomanhalli");
     Address address= new Address("560068", "Karnataka",strt);
     Student st= new Student("S-121","Sumit", address);
     ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
     String JasonString= mapper.writeValueAsString(st);
     System.out.println(JasonString);

      Student studnt= mapper.readValue(JasonString, Student.class);
      System.out.println(studnt);
```

Comment: Please do not forget to add below dependency 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>//You can change 
</dependency>